# Movable QGraphicsLineItem bounding box

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I’m trying to add a draggable QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem into pyqtgraph.plotItem.

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg

```
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

w = pg.PlotWidget()
w.show()

line = QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem()
line.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
line.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0), 2))
line.setLine(0, 0, 100, 100)

w.plotItem.addItem(line)

app.exec_()
```

However, there are several problems:
-   line width changes when the plot is zoomed
-   area where the dragging starts includes the whole rectangle bounding box (see picture below)
[image: drag_area]

I tried the following tricks:
1)

```
line.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIgnoresTransformations)
w.plotItem.addItem(line)
```

2)

```
line.setParentItem(w.plotItem.vb)
```

But the dragging area problem still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here goes the solution. When we use QtGui.QGraphicsLineItem:

1) For "line width changes when the plot is zoomed" problem,
use pen.setCosmetic(True) or create pen with pg.mkPen

2) For "area where the dragging starts includes the whole rectangle bounding box (see picture below)" problem,
use mouseDragEvent instead of using line.setFlag(QtGui.QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [LineSegmentRoi](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/roi.html) from pyqtgraph.

```
line = pg.LineSegmentROI([0, 100], [0, 0], pen=(255, 0, 0))
w.plotItem.addItem(line)
```